# How can I join the telegram chat bot using the referral link?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

And this is my program code:

```
chn = 'https://t.me/Crypto_Claimer_Bot?start=1003997020'

channel_entity = client.get_entity(chn)

print('LOGIN DENGAN @'+myself.username+'\n')

client.send_message(entity=channel_entity, message='/start')
```

When I run my program, there is an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ulang.py", line 55, in <module>
    channel_entity = client.get_entity(chn)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/sync.py", line 39, in syncified
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 311, in get_entity
    result.append(await self._get_entity_from_string(x))
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 546, in _get_entity_from_string
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "https://t.me/Crypto_Claimer_Bot?start=1003997020"
```

From this error, what should I change in my program code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the link you have isn't an `entity`. You should be able to use as an entity the part of the link before the `?`. So you better split the link into two parts.

```
link = 'https://t.me/Crypto_Claimer_Bot?start=1003997020'
bot_link , refereal = link.split('?')
message = f'/start {refereal.split('=')[1]}'
await client.send_message(bot_link, message)
```